# How to change the styles of each array elements separately?

Tags: css, react-native

How can I set a different background color for each Note?

```
export default class Note extends React.Component { render() {
return (
  <View key={this.props.keyval} style = {[styles.note , this.props.notecolor]} > 
  <ScrollView>
     <Text style ={styles.text} >{ this.props.val.note}</Text>
  </ScrollView>
  <View style ={styles.datte}>
     <Text style ={styles.date}>{ this.props.val.date}</Text>
  </View></View>
);}}
```

The notecolor has a background color attribute

```
 notecolor: { backgroundColor: 'orange' }
```

I set up some buttons to change the value, but the problem is when I add the second note, the first note also get the same bk color and so on for the others they all get the same background color depending on the last note added.

```
 let notes = this.state.noteArray.map((val, key) => {
  return (
    <Note key={key} keyval={key} val={val} notecolor={this.state.notecolor} />
  );
});
```

any help!

Comment: You need to show the component where you are using the note.

Comment: it is a note array and it's inside a scroll View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `this.state.notecolor` to keep the color, when you update the state, the whole page will re-render. Thats why every `note` will have the same background color.

Here are 2 different tricks to do what you are trying to achieve.

**Option 1**

Store your `notecolor` as a properties of the `note` object in your `noteArray`. For example,

```js
class MainApp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      noteArray : [
        {
          note: "Hello world!",
          date: "2019-01-01",
          notecolor: "orange",
        }, 
        {
          note: "Hola world!",
          date: "2019-01-01",
          notecolor: "green",
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  render() {
    <View>
      {
        this.state.noteArray.map((val, key) => {
          return (
            <Note key={key} keyval={key} val={val} notecolor={val.notecolor} switchColor={this.switchColor} />
          );
        });
      }
    </View>
  }

  switchColor = (color, key) => {
    var noteArray = {this.state};
    noteArray[key]["notecolor"] = color;
    this.setState({
      noteArray
    })
  }
}
```

To use switchColor on `note`, you just have to call it like this

```js
this.props.switchColor(newColor, this.props.key);
```

**Option 2**

Store `notecolor` on a separate array. ** Option 1 is a cleaner way to do it, if you dont mind the extra property

```js
noteArray = [
  {
    note: "Hello world!",
    date: "2019-01-01",
  }, 
  {
    note: "Hola world!",
    date: "2019-01-01",
  }
];

noteColorArray = ["orage", "green"];
```

To change the color

```js
switchColor = (color, key) => {
  var noteColorArray = {this.state};
  noteArray[key] = color;
  this.setState({
    noteColorArray
  })
}
```

**Finally**

To render your notes

```js
let notes = this.state.noteArray.map((val, key) => {
  return (
    <Note key={key} keyval={key} val={val} notecolor={val.notecolor} />
    // OR, depends on which option you choose
    <Note key={key} keyval={key} val={val} notecolor={this.state.noteColorArray[key]} />
  );
});
```

Comment: the function switch color i should add it in note file or in the main app?

Comment: you need to add the function on `note` file. Have you sort it out already?

Comment: but how it is being called ? shouldn't i add this.props.color?

Comment: i am sorry, i dont know why i told you to add the function in `note` earlier, lol. You need to add it on the main app, the file where you have the `noteArray` on. If you want to use it in `note`, pass the function as a prop `<Note ... switchColor={this.switchColor}/>`

Comment: i'm really confused can you help me pls i don't know how to add notecolor to the 'note' and how to pass the function to it too

Comment: i somehow found another easy lol i don't know how, anyway i directy `notecolor={ this.state.noteArray[key]["noteColor"]}` and it worked perfectly

Comment: and i used another variable to make it dynamic so when user push one of the colored buttons i set up earlier that variable take the button's color and bind it to the noteArray notecolor and it is working perfectly, thanks a lot man!

Comment: Cool! Im glad i cloud help